# Can't use ctrl+c to kill process in VM

Tags: redhat, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vblock

We are running several RHEL 6 64-bit VM's in a vBlock infrastructure using vCenter 5.5. If I open a console session through the vSphere web client the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> keystroke will not work. This is very inconvenient as a simple ping is now unstoppable. If I access the same VM through the vSphere desktop client or SSH session, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> works as expected. The VM's have the VMware tools installed.

Comment: What web browser and OS are you using on your client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [VMware and a browser issue](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2524446).

- **Try a different web browser:** If you're on a Mac, this can be an issue with Safari and Chrome. Firefox works fine.
- **Download the VMware Remote Console (VMRC) application:** It's a standalone application that likely doesn't have this problem.
- **Don't use the web console:** I mainly manage Linux VMs. I still use the thick client for this sort of activity. Otherwise, SSH.

Comment: For clarification: It was the browser. I am on a Mac and Firefox is the only browser that works correctly (tested Safari and Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

You can switch to another console, log in to a new session, and then kill the ping process running in the first console.

To switch consoles, just press Alt while pressing the left or right arrow keys.  This take me through 6 different consoles.